# Lamp stack not supporting phpmyadmin?

Tags: server, phpmyadmin

I have install lamp stack + word-press in my Ubuntu 16.04, in that apache2 ,  word-press is running but when i try to run phpmyadmin is not running i need to create new database so how to run phpmyadmin ?